# Is there a Visual Studio template for .NET MAUI Community Toolkit C# Markup?

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am interested in trying out C# Markup, but could not find any Visual Studio template on my own. Did I miss something or is there really none?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we don’t have one! It definitely is an interesting idea though. You should bring that up on the repository!

On that same repository there is a sample app: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui.Markup/tree/main/samples/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup.Sample

Also, there is a real-world app called GitTrends, that is an actual app that is released to the stores and is open-source: https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends

The latter is still on Xamarin, but the syntax should be pretty much the same.